How to alternate between two numbers when a button is clicked in Tkinter?
I am trying to set up a button in Tkinter to start displaying "12", and to change to "X" when clicked. I have managed this, but I also want it to change back to "12" when clicked again, which I can't figure out. Essentially it should alternate between "12" and "X" upon being clicked.
I'm trying to use an if statement to do this, but it isn't working. Below is what I've got so far:
import tkinter

class MyGUI:

   def __init__ (self):
    
     self.window = tkinter.Tk()
     self.state = (self.button1["12"]) 
     
    
     self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.window, text=("12"), font=('Arial',18), background=("red"), command=self.change_state)
     self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)


     self.window.mainloop()

   def change_state(self):
    
    if self.state["12"] == True:
      self.button1(self.window, self.button1.config(text="X"))
    else:
       self.button1(self.window, self.button1.config(text="12"))
    


MyGUI()

Which generates this error:
'MyGUI' object has no attribute 'button1'
I really appreciate any help,and please note I'm very new to programming and am learning Python for fun.

Comment this #self.state = (self.button1["12"])

The error obviously tells you that when the line self.state = (self.button1["12"]) is executed, self.button1 has not been created.


to start displaying "12", and to change to "X" when clicked. I have
managed this, but I also want it to change back to "12" when clicked
again, which I can't figure out. Essentially it should alternate
between "12" and "X" upon being clicked.

The problem can be fixed.
Comment out this #self.state = (self.button1["12"])
Don't use state for Button widget. Use configure for Button widget. The state only tells True or False.
Snippet re-wrote:
import tkinter

class MyGUI:

   def __init__ (self):
    
     self.window = tkinter.Tk()
     #self.state = (self.button1["12"]) 
      
     self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.window, text=("12"), font=('Arial',18), background=("red"), command=self.change_state)
     self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

     self.window.mainloop()

   def change_state(self):
    
    #if self.button1['state'] == tkinter.NORMAL:
        #self.button1.config(text="X")
    #elif self.button1.config[text=="X"]:
       #self.button1.config(text="12")

    if self.button1.configure('text')[-1] == 12:
        self.button1.configure(text="X")
        
    else:
        self.button1.configure(text =12)
                              

MyGUI()

Screenshot:


I can even do like this:     if self.button1.configure('text')[-1] == 12:
text="X"
else:
    text = 12
self.button1.configure(text=text)


it works. Nice.

import tkinter

# Remove braces
class MyGUI:

   # define window and state as self variable
   def __init__ (self, window,state='12'):
       self.window = window
       self.state = state    
           
       self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.window, text= self.state, font=('Arial',18), bg="red", command=self.change_state)
       self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)     

   def change_state(self):
    
       # 1.You should not declare button once again while configuring
       # 2. As the condion is if self.state == '12', declare self.state for both conditions and make it as text
       if self.state == '12' :
           self.state = 'X'
           self.button1.config(text= self.state, bg="red")
       else:
           self.state = '12'
           self.button1.config(text= self.state, bg="red")     
     
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # declare window here
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    app = MyGUI(window)
    window.mainloop()


I delete my answer. I upvote .

@toyotaSupra, omg. why did you delete? I didn't see yours. I know there are other ways of presenting.

You can see my answer.

Btw, you don't duplicate self.button.config. You can do this:  self.state = 'X'
color_bg="red"
       #self.button1.config(text= self.state, bg="red")
   else:
       self.state = '12'
       color_bg="red"
   self.button1.config(text= self.state, bg=color_bg)  #<+= U can use one self.button1.config


If i do that, the text doesn't change from X to 12. (It changes from 12 to X, but not from X to 12). Only then I added.

In your method, only configure will be sufficient whereas it is not so here.

In your constructor you are referencing button1 before you created it. So just change self.state to True, at the start. Then in your change_state method when you check to see if self.state == True, you also need to change it to False for the next time you click the button. And when it is False you need to change it to True, like:
if self.state == True:
    self.button1.config(text="X")
    self.state = False
else:
    self.button1.config(text="12")
    self.state = True

And as shown above you need to change the two lines that modify the button's text.

line 16, in change_state
if self.state == True:
^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyGUI' object has no attribute 'state'

@toyotaSupra Second sentence, I changed self.state["12"] to self.state. But maybe it was not as clear as I meant it to be.

@toyotaSupra On reflection I don't think your comment was meant for me.

It is the same as @Daniel Paul..  I tested this     def change_state(self):
if self.state:
self.button1.config(text="X")
    else:
        self.button1.config(text="12")
    self.state = not self.state   in your script


You don't need duplicate self.state =

@toyotaSupra I deliberately did not do it that way, as the OP clearly stated that he is  very new to programming. It is not always clear how much new people have learned. And as you see from his latest comment he needs an explanation of that expression.
